# functor with an inner state in thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, functor, thrust

Im trying to go through two vectors, compute the difference between coordinates, compute some more force using mass etc and actualize the value of acceleration on each loop the thrust::for_each does. However, I'm unable to keep track of the acceleration value.

Using Thrust and functors, I've managed to write this:

This is the functor that causes me trouble:

```
struct ParticleGenerator::acc_func{
    //stores the initial coordinates if i-th particle to use it for computation and the init. acc. that is 0.0f
    acc_func(float Ax, float Bx, float Cx, int X, int Y, int Z) : ax(Ax), bx(Bx), cx(Cx),  _x(X), _y(Y), _z(Z) {}

    template <typename Tuple>
    __device__ __host__
    void operator()(Tuple t){
            //thrust::get<0>(t) +=(int) 32;
            // save some values
            acc[0] = thrust::get<0>(t);  //(#)
            acc[1] = thrust::get<1>(t);
            acc2[0] = acc[0];
            acc2[1] = acc[1];
            //retrieve them, OK
            printf("%d_%d\n", acc[0], acc[1]); //works well
    }


    int getRes(){
            //return saved values, not OK
            printf("%d_%d_%d_%d\n", acc[0], acc[1], acc2[0], acc2[1]); //prints wrong values

            return 0;
    }

    //this returns the correct value, though
    int getRes2(){ return _x;}

    int acc2[2];
private:
        float ax, bx, cx;
        int _x, _y, _z;
        int temp;
        int acc[2];
};
```

as you can see, I've tried both public and private, also tried using just simple int (*temp*) to store any value but the function *getRes()* when used as below never returns the correct value.

I've noticed that the part *_x(X)*(scroll right to see the full constructor of acc_func()) stores the value correctly and I am able to retrieve it with the function *getRes()*.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way how to replicate this behavior? To use the command on line marked with //(#) and successfully save, update and later return the value?

and this is my thrust loop:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecPosX.size(); ++i){   
    acc_func AF(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, vecPosX[i], vecPosY[i], vecPosZ[i]);
    thrust::for_each(
                      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(vecPosX.begin(), vecPosY.begin())),
                      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(vecPosX.end(), vecPosY.end())),
                    AF
                    );
    AF.getRes();
    //use the AF.getRes() to save the values of the acceleration and
    //update the vecPosX[i], vecPosY[i] etc accordingly
}
```

where vecPosX, vecPosY are the vectors that contaion X and Y positions of the particle

the whole idea is to create a tuple(posX, posY) and on each *thrust::for_each* loop recompute and actualize the acceleration and when the computation is done, simply return the results of acceleration x and y so that i can update the speed and position of the i-th particle

here are the two different results:

```
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
0_4_-588854768_32764
267_264_267_264
254_272_254_272
256_237_256_237
264_264_264_264
259_228_259_228
259_247_259_247
264_245_264_245
265_237_265_237
272_260_272_260
```

I hope you can help me, thank you :)

**edit:** please note that I've written this whole simulation application successfully using SDL, Visual Studio and two for loops one inside each other, right now I'm trying to make it faster to be able to use more particles

**edit 2:** to replicate the problem, one could use

```
thrust::device_vector<int> vecPosX(10, 10;
thrust::device_vector<int> vecPosY(10, 10);
thrust::device_vector<int> vecPosZ(10, 10);
```

to create the vectors and some values

**edit 3:**

I apologize for my bad explanation, please bear with me.
Here is a complete, simple, compilable and runnable example of expected and unexpected results:

example.cu:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

thrust::device_vector<int> vecPosX(5, 10);
thrust::device_vector<int> vecPosY(5, 10);

struct acc_func {
    acc_func(int X, int Y) : _x(X), _y(Y) {}

    template <typename Tuple>
    __device__ __host__
    void operator()(Tuple t){
            acc2[0] = _x;
            acc2[1] = _y;
            acc[0] += 1;
            acc[1] += 1;
    }


    void expected(){
        printf("expected:\t%d:%d:and:%d:%d\n", 5, 5, _x, _y);
        return;
    }

    void not_expected(){
        printf("unexpected:\t%d:%d:nor:%d:%d\n\n", acc[0], acc[1], acc2[0], acc2[1]);
        return;
    }

public:
        int acc2[2];
private:
        int _x, _y;
        int acc[2] = {0, 0};
};


int main(){

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecPosX.size(); ++i){
        acc_func AF(vecPosX[i], vecPosY[i]);
        thrust::for_each(
            thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(vecPosX.begin(),vecPosY.begin())),                      

            thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(vecPosX.end(), vecPosY.end())),
            AF
          );
        AF.expected();
        AF.not_expected();
    }

    return 0;


}
```

results:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 example.cu -o example
$ ./example
expected:       5:5:and:10:10
unexpected:     0:0:nor:19:0

expected:       5:5:and:10:10
unexpected:     0:0:nor:19:0

expected:       5:5:and:10:10
unexpected:     0:0:nor:19:0

expected:       5:5:and:10:10
unexpected:     0:0:nor:19:0

expected:       5:5:and:10:10
unexpected:     0:0:nor:19:0
```

**edit 4**

What I'm trying to achieve is re-write the following code:

```
float ax, ay, az, dx, dy, dz;
float invr, invr3, f;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++){
    ax = 0.0;
    ay = 0.0;
    az = 0.0;


    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < particles.size(); j++){
        dx = (float) (particles[j]->mPosX - particles[i]->mPosX);
        dy = (float) (particles[j]->mPosY - particles[i]->mPosY);
        dz = (float) (particles[j]->mPosZ - particles[i]->mPosZ);
        invr = (float) 1.0/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + 100);
        invr3 = invr*invr*invr;
        f = particles[j]->mass * invr3;
        ax += f*dx;
        ay += f*dy;
        az += f*dz;
    }
    particles[i]->mPosX = particles[i]->mPosX + (int) dt*particles[i]->xVel + (int) 0.5*dt*dt*ax;
    particles[i]->mPosY = particles[i]->mPosY + (int) dt*particles[i]->yVel + (int) 0.5*dt*dt*ay;
    particles[i]->mPosZ = particles[i]->mPosZ + (int) dt*particles[i]->zVel + (int) 0.5*dt*dt*az;
    particles[i]->xVel += dt*ax;
    particles[i]->yVel += dt*ay;
    particles[i]->zVel += dt*az;
}
```

My intention was to keep the outer loop pretty much as it is, compute the *ax*, *ay*, *az* using thrust (because it's going over a bunch of elements in a vector) and update the vectors with the result the of thrust *for_each*.

How can I safely count the *ax*, *ay* and *az* and return it?

the *particles* you see is

```
std::vector<Particle *> particles;
```

and *Particle* is a class that has member variables

```
int mPosX, mPoY, mPosZ;
float xVel, yVel, zVel;
int mass;
```

and dt is:

```
const float dt = 0.1f;
```

So instead of a class that contains ints, and floats I've created vectors of ints and floats so that i-th element of each vector (vector of mass, speed, position) corresponds to information about one specific particle

Comment: Sorry, but I have read through this three times now, and I don't understand what it is you are trying to ask here. Your question says "I've noticed that the part _x(X) stores the value correctly" but I don't see anything by that name anywhere in the code you posted. Could you perhaps try simplifying the question a bit and explain exactly what you are trying to do here?

Comment: you have to scroll right: "acc_func(float Ax, float Bx, float Cx, int X, int Y, int Z) : ax(Ax), bx(Bx), cx(Cx),  _x(X), _y(Y), _z(Z) {}". _x(X) stores the value into "_x" and later from the function "getRes" I can return _x and the value makes sense

Comment: please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including sample input data, current output and desired output. as it is currently written, I have no idea what you try to calculate and where that actually fails.

Comment: ok, I've edited the post, sorry about the communication noise

Comment: OK now things are a lot clearer. And there is a *lot* wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems here which mean that this won't ever work as you imagine. In no particular order:

1. In your loop, you construct a `acc_func` instance and *pass it by value* to a `for_each` call. The GPU is operating on a *copy* of AF. So when you call `not_expected` you are printing out the values of the host's original, not the copy the GPU actually operated on.
2. Within the functor you do this:

   ```
      acc[0] += 1;
      acc[1] += 1;
   ```

   Those are a memory race. Every thread launched by the thrust `for_each`(and you can't know how many that is) will be simultaneously be trying to increment those values, leading to read-after-write memory hazards. CUDA does have atomic memory functions, but that would be a terribly inefficient way to achieve what your code is trying to do.

Because your application isn't well explained, I can't really advise you what the right way to do whatever it is you are doing with thrust, but the errors in your functor design in the edit suggest that you have some fairly serious changes to make to the design before it will work.

Finally, just a comment, but don't ever declare thrust vectors at global scope. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869167/cuda-calling-kernel-outside-main-function/24883665#24883665) as to why.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how do I pass the AF correctly so that I read from the struct that GPU worked with? Also I've added some more info about my application, could you take a look and point me into the right direction?

Comment: @kn0t3k: The one sentence answer is that you can't.  Functors aren't intended to be data containers and there is no way to recover state from them after a data parallel operation.  You will have to think of another way to do this.

Comment: I just got an idea, I might create three more vectors, lets call them vecAccX, vecAccY, vecAccZ, pass them to make_tuple and store each result of the loop into one element of this vecAcc vector using iterator. When the computation is done, I could simply add all the elements and get the result. However I'm not sure whether this solution is going to take a lot of GPU/memory time ... but it's a good starting point I guess