# Using host class member pointing to device memory in device code

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to have an instance of a Container class allocating some device and host memory on initialization. I want to use the allocated memory in device code, without passing the actual pointer (for API reasons).

How do I create a global `__device__` pointer to the member pointing to the device memory? I am happy to use thrust if that helps.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Container {
    int *h_int = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    int *d_int;
    Container() {
        h_int[0] = 6; h_int[1] = 6; h_int[2] = 6; h_int[3] = 6;
        cudaMalloc(&d_int, 4*sizeof(int));
        memcpyHostToDevice();
    }
    void memcpyHostToDevice() {
        cudaMemcpy(d_int, h_int, 4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
    void memcpyDeviceToHost() {
        cudaMemcpy(h_int, d_int, 4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }
};

Container stuff;


__device__ auto d_int = &stuff.d_int;  // How do I get that right?


__global__ void edit() {  // To keep the API simple I do not want to pass the pointer
    auto i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    d_int[i] = 1 + 2*(i > 0) + 4*(i > 2);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    edit<<<4, 1>>>();
    stuff.memcpyDeviceToHost();
    std::cout << stuff.h_int[0] << stuff.h_int[1] << stuff.h_int[2] << stuff.h_int[3] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You can't statically inititalize a `__device__` variable in the way you are trying to (and the value you are trying to apply isn't correct either). The CUDA runtime API contains a function for initialising global scope device symbols. Use that instead.
2. Your global scope declaration of `stuff` shouldn't work either for a number of subtle reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24869167/681865) (it is technically undefined behaviour). Declare it at `main` scope instead.

Putting these two things together should lead your to do something like this instead:

```
__device__ int* d_int;

// ...

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    Container stuff;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_int, &stuff.dint, sizeof(int*));

    edit<<<4, 1>>>();

    // ...
```

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t1199.cu
#include <iostream>


struct Container {
    int *h_int = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    int *d_int;
    Container() {
        h_int[0] = 6; h_int[1] = 6; h_int[2] = 6; h_int[3] = 6;
        cudaMalloc(&d_int, 4*sizeof(int));
        memcpyHostToDevice();
    }
    void memcpyHostToDevice() {
        cudaMemcpy(d_int, h_int, 4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
    void memcpyDeviceToHost() {
        cudaMemcpy(h_int, d_int, 4*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }
};

//Container stuff;


__device__ int  *d_int; // = &stuff.d_int;  // How do I get that right?


__global__ void edit() {  // To keep the API simple I do not want to pass the pointer
    auto i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    d_int[i] = 1 + 2*(i > 0) + 4*(i > 2);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Container stuff;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_int, &stuff.d_int, sizeof(int *));
    edit<<<4, 1>>>();
    stuff.memcpyDeviceToHost();
    std::cout << stuff.h_int[0] << stuff.h_int[1] << stuff.h_int[2] << stuff.h_int[3] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o t1199 t1199.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1199
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1337
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Actually it does work if I declare `stuff` in global scope. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @qiv: You cannot rely on it working. It is undefined behaviour and it will stop working on you at some point.

Comment: Might this be the reason behind this strange problem: in a test case momentum is often only conserved at the first execution, but not in consecutive executions? Declaring the solver class non global avoids it (as does printing the coordinates in the kernel or changing the order of the tests ...).

Comment: @qiv how could anyone possibly answer that? If you have a specific question about a piece of code (and clearly it is not this code),  then ask a new question.

Comment: I am considering it, but I would probably need ~400 lines of code to reproduce it ...