# Having thrust::device_vector in global scope

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm writing a program that calculates a lot of properties of triangle mesh data. Some of these properties, I'd like to calculate using thrust:: methods, other properties need to be calculated using raw memory pointers in CUDA kernels.

To transfer the data to the GPU I've got this in a **transfer.cu** file, (since creating and manipulating `thrust::device_vector`s in plain C++ code is not supported):

```
// thrust vectors (global)
thrust::host_vector<glm::vec3> trianglethrust_host;
thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3> trianglethrust_device;

extern "C" void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const trimesh::TriMesh *mesh, float** triangles) {
// fill host vector
for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->faces.size(); i++) {
    // PUSHING DATA INTO HOST_VECTOR HERE (OMITTED FOR CLARITY)
} 
// copy to GPU by assigning host vector to device vector, like in the Thrust documentation
trianglethrust_device = trianglethrust_host;
// save raw pointer
*triangles = (float*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&(trianglethrust_device[0]));
}
```

This function `trianglestoGPU_thrust`is called from the main method of my C++ program.
All works fine and dandy, until the program exits, and the (globally defined) trianglethrust_device vector goes out of scope. Thrust tries to free it, but the CUDA context is already gone, resulting in a `cudaErrorInvalidDevicePointer`

What would be considered best practice for my problem?

TL;DR: *I want a thrust::device_vector that lives for the duration of my program, since I want to throw thrust:: functions (like transform etc) at it, as well as read and manipulate it through raw pointer access in CUDA.*

**Solution:**
In my case, I appearantly was free-ing using the raw data pointer somewhere further in the process. Removing that free, and ending my main loop with

```
trianglethrust_device.clear();
trianglethrust_device.shrink_to_fit();
trianglethrust_device.device_vector~;
```

To force the clearing of that vector before the CUDA runtime gets torn down. This worked, but is probably still a pretty ugly way of doing this.

I recommend **Robert's answer** on this one, and will mark it as valid.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24869167/681865 for a general explanation of what is happening and why the problem occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already discovered, the thrust vector container itself cannot be placed at file scope.

One possible solution is to simply create the vectors you need at the beginning of `main`, then pass references to these to whatever functions need them.

If you really want "global behavior" you could place pointers to vectors at global/file scope, then initialize the needed vectors at the beginning of main, and set the pointers at global scope to point to the vectors created in main.

Based on the question in the comment I guess it's important/desirable that the main file be a `.cpp` file compiled with the host compiler.  Therefore we can use the previously mentioned concepts combined with allocation of the vectors on the heap so as to avoid deallocation until the program terminates.  Here's a full example:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include "transfer.h"

int main(){

  float **triangles, *mesh;
  triangles = new float *[1];
  mesh = new float[4];
  mesh[0] = 0.1f; mesh[1] = 0.2f; mesh[2] = 0.3f;
  trianglesToGPU_thrust(mesh, triangles);
  do_global_work(triangles);
  finish();
}
$ cat transfer.h
void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const float *, float **);
void do_global_work(float **);
void finish();
$ cat transfer.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include "transfer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

__global__ void k(float *data, size_t ds){
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) printf("%f,", data[i]);
}

// thrust vectors (global)
thrust::host_vector<float> *trianglethrust_host;
thrust::device_vector<float> *trianglethrust_device;

void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const float *mesh, float** triangles) {
//create vectors
  trianglethrust_host = new thrust::host_vector<float>;
  trianglethrust_device = new thrust::device_vector<float>;

// fill host vector
  size_t i = 0;
  while (mesh[i] != 0.0f) {
    (*trianglethrust_host).push_back(mesh[i++]);
  }
// copy to GPU by assigning host vector to device vector, like in the Thrust documentation
  *trianglethrust_device = *trianglethrust_host;
// save raw pointer
  *triangles = (float*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&((*trianglethrust_device)[0]));
}

void do_global_work(float** triangles){

  std::cout << "from device vector:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy((*trianglethrust_device).begin(), (*trianglethrust_device).end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "from kernel:" << std::endl;
  k<<<1,1>>>(*triangles, (*trianglethrust_device).size());
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void finish(){
  if (trianglethrust_host) delete trianglethrust_host;
  if (trianglethrust_device) delete trianglethrust_device;
}
$ nvcc -c transfer.cu
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ -o test main.o transfer.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
$ ./test
from device vector:
0.1,0.2,0.3,
from kernel:
0.100000,0.200000,0.300000,
$
```

Here's another approach, similar to the previous, using a `std::vector` of thrust containers, at global scope (only the `transfer.cu` file is different from the previous example, `main.cpp` and `transfer.h` are the same):

```
$ cat transfer.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include "transfer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <vector>

__global__ void k(float *data, size_t ds){
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) printf("%f,", data[i]);
}

// thrust vectors (global)
std::vector<thrust::host_vector<float> > trianglethrust_host;
std::vector<thrust::device_vector<float> > trianglethrust_device;

void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const float *mesh, float** triangles) {
//create vectors
  trianglethrust_host.resize(1);
  trianglethrust_device.resize(1);

// fill host vector
size_t i = 0;
  while (mesh[i] != 0.0f) {
    trianglethrust_host[0].push_back(mesh[i++]);
  }
// copy to GPU by assigning host vector to device vector, like in the Thrust documentation
  trianglethrust_device[0] = trianglethrust_host[0];
// save raw pointer
  *triangles = (float*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(trianglethrust_device[0].data());
}

void do_global_work(float** triangles){

  std::cout << "from device vector:" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(trianglethrust_device[0].begin(), trianglethrust_device[0].end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "from kernel:" << std::endl;
  k<<<1,1>>>(*triangles, trianglethrust_device[0].size());
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void finish(){
  trianglethrust_host.clear();
  trianglethrust_device.clear();
}
$ nvcc -c transfer.cu
$ g++ -o test main.o transfer.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
$ ./test
from device vector:
0.1,0.2,0.3,
from kernel:
0.100000,0.200000,0.300000,
$
```

Comment: I've modified the function to `void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const trimesh::TriMesh *mesh, float** triangles, thrust::host_vector<glm::vec3>& host, thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3>& device)`. But when I try to declare a device_vector in standard C++ code, I run into a compilation problem, similar to the one here: https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/526

I'll quote Jared: _Constructing `device_vector` is not intended to work unless you are compiling with CUDA support. I'm closing this, as everything indicates this is working as intended._

Comment: True, so you would have to compile your main routine with `nvcc` in a `.cu` file.   I've updated my answer to provide another alternative to address this case.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent overview and answer. **Plot twist:** Turns out in my original question, somewhere deep down in the code, I already did _cudaFree_ on the raw pointer, which didn't help the out-of-scope-going cleanup process. In addition to your excellent answers, another possible solution is to explicitly `clear` , `shrink_to_fit` and call the destructor on the global device_vector before main goes out of scope.

Comment: For the project itself, I made a version where I make the pointers in my c++ main method and deliver pointer-to-pointers of them to the functions in the .cu file, turning the function declaration into `void trianglesToGPU_thrust(const trimesh::TriMesh *mesh, float** triangles, thrust::host_vector<glm::vec3>** hostpoint, thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3>** devicepoint);`

Yay or nay? This allows me to pass around (pointers) to the device_vector in my C++ file, and even pass it to other .cu modules for work, which would be harder in your example, I think.